# XML data and JavaScript, weird results

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm having trouble accessing data from an XML document using the code below:

```
function request(url) {

        var xmlhttp;

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return xmlhttp.responseText;
}

    var data = request("data/data.xml");

            if (window.DOMParser) {
                parser = new DOMParser();
                xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "text/xml");
            }
            else // Internet Explorer
            {
                xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = false;
                xmlDoc.loadXML(data);
            }

var nodes = xmlDoc.documentElement.childNodes;
```

the variable `nodes` contains the `NodeList` below.  I don't understand where the `Empty text node`s come from though.

```
<NodeList length="25">
  Text - Empty text node
  <book id="bk101"></book>
  Text - Empty text node
  <book id="bk102"></book>
  Text - Empty text node
  <book id="bk103"></book>
  Text - Empty text node
  <book id="bk104"></book>
  Text - Empty text node
  <book id="bk105"></book>
  Text - Empty text node
  <book id="bk106"></book>
  Text - Empty text node
  <book id="bk107"></book>
  Text - Empty text node
  <book id="bk108"></book>
  Text - Empty text node
  <book id="bk109"></book>
  Text - Empty text node
  <book id="bk110"></book>
  Text - Empty text node
  <book id="bk111"></book>
  Text - Empty text node
  <book id="bk112"></book>
  Text - Empty text node
  </NodeList>
</NodeList>
```

If I use this instead: `nodes = xmlDoc.documentElement`, the variable contains this content:

```
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101"></book>
  <book id="bk102"></book>
  <book id="bk103"></book>
  <book id="bk104"></book>
  <book id="bk105"></book>
  <book id="bk106"></book>
  <book id="bk107"></book>
  <book id="bk108"></book>
  <book id="bk109"></book>
  <book id="bk110"></book>
  <book id="bk111"></book>
  <book id="bk112"></book>
</catalog>
```

But if I use `.childNodes` to access the child nodes in the collection, the empty text nodes reappear.

I would like to know if there is a better way to access XML data using JavaScript, I have tried XPath, but its apparently not supported well in IE.

I'm using the book.xml example data from Microsoft.

## Update

This works:

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("author")[0]
y = x.childNodes[0];
alert(y.nodeValue);
```

Comment: Whitespaces(e.g. linebreaks) are nodes too

Comment: use `children` instead of `childNodes`, it will skip whitespace

Comment: `children` returns undefined?

Comment: [`.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) is a HTML-specific property. However, `document.getElementsByTagName("book")` should work

Comment: Yes document.getElementsByTagName("book") Works, but i am unable to access the content of the nodes?